# Openshift Django Scaling

Tags: python, django, openshift

I'm creating `Django` app on `OpenShift` on `Python 3.3` with `no scaling`, it works fine. So when I browse the app gives me a django url error and with /admin brings me the admin login page.

But as I create it with `scaling` I get this error

> 503 Service Unavailable
>
> No server is available to handle this request.

I tried with `small`, `small high.cpu` none works for me with scaling but actually I need `small high.cpu` on `eu.west` region.

I also tried to create a `Python 3.3` app with `Scaling` which works fine and then add Django through repository upstream or by adding my previous configuration with I had before still not working after complete push to repo.

I've done that before and had worked for me before, so please don't answer without testing it.

This is the link to [HAProxy](http://prod-ratma.rhcloud.com/haproxy-status/)  both local gear and backend are DOWN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there's something wrong with the [current](https://github.com/openshift/django-example.git) django quickstart for openshift. In your case the scaled app is returing a `503 error` because the django app is producing a `404 error` at it's root.

I've successfully deployed both scaling and none scaling using this repo: https://github.com/jsvgoncalves/django-openshift

Don't forget that the `$OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION` environment variable needs to point to the right `wsgi.py` and that you may need to restart the app.

```
$ APP_NAME=yourapp
$ rhc env set OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION=django_exp/wsgi.py -a $APP_NAME
# You may need to restart your app
$ rhc app-restart -a $APP_NAME
```

Also, create the database (or have it directly on your git repo, as everytime you'll push changes this database file will disappear):

```
$ rhc ssh -a $APP_NAME
$ cd app-root/runtime/repo
$ python manage.py migrate
```